# What causes TypeError in Apollo Client?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am looking at an error report from Apollo Client. I am not able to reproduce the issue and it doesn't appear to happen often, but I would like to figure out what is going on and perhaps open an issue on github with the project if this may be caused by the library. In my scan of the current issues, I can't find this one listed anywhere.

The image shows the data populated in `error` provided by `onError` of the `useQuery` hook.

Any guidance to help resolve this is appreciated! Thank you!

[image: The data populated in error provided by onError of the useQuery hook]

Comment: Could you share the relevant query and resolver where you're seeing this issue? This seems most likely related to the server side not providing a valid gql type.